# C/C++ trick: define a unified type for multiple different types?

Tags: c++, c, types, compilation, clang

I am working on some compiler thing and I have multiple different types:

```
Box*
BoxedInt*
BoxedString*
...
```

They are all basically pointers to different objects, I want to create a unified type, called `ObjectPointer` that can represent all these pointer types. I am inclined to use `void *` because I do not want to have casting everywhere. What can I do? Can I do something like:

```
typedef Box*      ObjectPointer
typedef BoxedInt* ObjectPointer
....
```

or there are some other way to do it? I just want a `algebraic data type` like thing for these pointers. By the way I am using `clang`.

I intend to use the new type `ObjectPointer` just as an usual type. It should not be a class or struct or union. Say if I have a function `Box* add(BoxedInt* lhs, BoxedInt rhs)` after the change it should be just `ObjectPointer add(ObjectPointer lhs, ObjectPointer rhs)`.

Comment: Are you not allowed to change the definitions of these classes to inherit from `ObjectPointer`?

Comment: Depends on how you intend to use this combined type. Please add more details about that.

Comment: So, which language are you using? Please also remove the tags from the title, they don't belong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C`, you can use a `union` type, that contains pointers of all the elements described above:

```
union UnifiedType {
  Box* boxPtr;
  BoxedInt* boxedIntPrt;
  BoxedString* boxedStringPtr;
};
```

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) for more.

In `C++` though, you can use an (abstract if needed) superclass for all those types described and set them as extensions to it. Then, you can use a base class pointer for your needs. Look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) for more.

```
class BoxedBase { /*....*/ }

class Box : public BoxedBase { /*....*/ }
class BoxedInt : public BoxedBase { /*....*/ }
class BoxedString : public BoxedBase { /*....*/ }
```

You can then `typedef` the pointer as this:

```
typedef BoxedBase* ObjectPointer
```

Comment: `public class` and `public abstract class` are not C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define "This thing can hold any number of unrelated types." however, if you relate the types (using a base class) you can use polymorphism instead.

```
class Object { ... }
class Box : public Object { ... }
class BoxedInt : public Object { ... }
...
typedef Object * ObjectPointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question description, it sounds like you want to use templates. For example, if you write a function

```
template <typename T>
void ExampleFunction(T* object)
{
     //do boxy stuff
}
```

you can call it with all the types you are interested in, as long as a unified function definition makes sense. You can say `ExampleFunction(ptr)` where `ptr` has any type which would make sense when substituted for `T` in `ExampleFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you suggest, (i.e. use a void *) to point to all the objects, but I would only use this option after you have exhausted all other possibilities because you will have to void * cast it and lose all compiler size / type checks (effectively a re-interpretation cast).

**edit:** e.g. you may need to use this when you receive "known" data from an external source which has no type information like inter-processor messages or such.

Your best option is to base class your various box classes and have the other classes inherit them. This is generally the best way in c++, since your base-class pointer can point to any of the derived classes. You will still need to cast to access the final type (e.g. BoxedInt) but you can use the safer dynamic cast; generally you can use some sort of lookup function to do this, or a factory pattern...

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to solve this is polymorphism. So, as others have noted, in C++ you would write

```
class Object { ... };
class Box : public Object { ... };
class BoxedInt : public Box { ... };
class BoxedString : public Box { ... };
...
```

In C, you can do the exact same thing, even though it won't avoid the necessity to cast pointers:

```
typedef struct Object { ... } Object;
typedef struct Box { Object super; ... } Box;
typedef struct BoxedInt { Box super; ... } BoxedInt;
typedef struct BoxedString { Box super; ... } BoxedString;
```